# Is There an Alternate to CodeIgniter Throwing 500s?

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to learn CodeIgniter, and I'm constantly running into "500, Internal Server Error". So far, I've learned that that usually means I have a typo somewhere, but it still is kind of hard to find the typo because it doesn't tell you where it is.

Is there a way that I can tell CodeIgniter to tell me what's wrong rather than making Apache throw a "500, Internal Server Error"? I'm an intermediate PHP programmer, and I've thrown more 500 errors in the past two days with CodeIgniter than I have since I started coding PHP! Can I get CodeIgniter to tell me the syntax errors rather than having Apache give me 500s?

Comment: Why dont you check your error logs? Could be a whole range of things & pretty unanswerable.

Comment: Check your .htaccess and redirectings in php files

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: I guess I was looking for a way that the browser could tell me what's going on, instead of having to navigate to teh error logs and open them up. If that's what I have to do, I guess it's what I have to do.

Comment: @safarov: I'm not using any .htaccess files. I'm hosting my own server, so I use the apache2 config files.

Comment: than look inside your httpd.conf or vhost.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could give credit to Lawrence Cherone, because his comment really helped me solve my problem.

I started looking in the access and error logs and started finding what my errors were quite quickly. When I ran into those 500 errors, it solved my problems by looking at the apache2 logs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like these errors are caused by the CI function `show_error($message, $status=500)`. CI itself has a custom 500 error page, which does include any php errors that caused the 500 response (assuming of course your error reporting is turned on in php.ini and the CI `ENVIRONMENT` constant is not set to `'production'`).

If you are getting a generic 500 error page, it would seem that some setting in Apache is overriding the custom page sent by CI. As @safarov suggested try checking you Apache config or .htaccess files for an explicit 500 error response.

Comment: I looked in the configuration files, and nothing seemed to be be overriding the CI error page, and the CI config is set to report all errors in development, which is the environment it's set to.